# Is there a way to turn on Reading Mode on MIUI using terminal commands or adb?

Tags: screen, miui

**Background**

I have been using a Xiaomi device running MIUI8 and had the option of enabling **Reading Mode** (use of contrast colours to reduce blue light emision) on select Apps (which was great) but upon upgrading to MIUI9 this feature is now only available on system level i.e its either Reading mode is on/off thus you can't turn enable it automatically when you open a specific app and it doesn't automatically turn off after closing that app.

This is annoying because you have to manually enable and disable it. (Scheduling it is out of question because its its manual and you don't always use the specified app at the same time).

**My idea**

My proposed workaround is using a terminal command/adb together with tasker to enable **Reading mode** automatically when a specified app is opened, then have it turn off when done :). Right now I am not sure of the shell command to use, and which setting variable to target, perhaps somewhere in the settings database (I strongly feel the relevant file to modify in the file system is

```
data/data/com.android.providers.settings/databases/settings.db
```

**Question**

Is there a way to enable **Reading mode** using terminal command or similar. Any other workaround is appreciated ?

Comment: I don't think there is anything related in Settings database/xml files, at least in MIUI 10. I searched through the three lists, and found nothing related. Even in logcat, the relevant entry was `W         : [ColorAdjust_C3B] result = 0 eyemode= 0`. Eyemode changes to 5 when reading mode is turned on. I looked into system properties and found `persist.sys.display_eyecare` which also changes to 0 and 5. I think changing it directly or using resetprop of Magisk might achieve something. Unfortunately, I can't change it without root access, and I can't afford to root this phone (not mine).

Comment: @Firelord thanks a lot for this input, meanwhile let me see if I can figure out something with the leads you've given me